# AWS Glue not using all executors

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I am using some AWS glue to perform some ETL operations. My program writes a computed dataframe to S3. When I look at the metrics, i find that not all my executors are being used, infact just one is being used.
How do I make sure all my allocated executors are being busy ?
Thanks.
I do not use gluecontext in my program just native sparkcontext

Comment: Depend on what job is doing, the executor may be used just one or several ones.

Comment: I send some data from s3 as dataframs and then apply sql operations on them

Comment: Which format of the file? is that zipped or not? CSV can be loaded in parallel but JSON may mot.

Comment: Thanks Lamanus. It is csv

Answer (score 0):

Not using gluecontext could be one of the reason for one executor being used.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-profile-debug-straggler.html

Especially read **Memory Profile** section:

> After the first two stages, only executor number 3 is actively
>   consuming memory to process the data. The remaining executors are
>   simply idle or have been relinquished shortly after the completion of
>   the first two stages.

Comment: Thanks Sandeep for you response! I did look at the above link, in my case, i read few dataframes, perform some actions using them and form one single dataframe which I write as csv. Where do you suggest I can repartition my dataframe

Answer (score 0):

I found that my job was not using all the executors, despite having a lot of data to process. The problem was in the set up on my SparkContext. I was using `SparkContext.setMaster("local[*]")`, which I believe makes the job run on only one executor (driver). If that helps your problem or anyone else facing the same issue.

Comment: Then what should we set the context to make sure it runs on all nodes?

Comment: I ended up not having the `SparkContext.setMaster("local[*]")` command at all. By default, the SparkContext will, I believe, by default use all nodes as required.